# getting selected file path from galary/file manager

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

i am trying to get path of selected file but its returning me nothing.... Here is the code i am trying, but i am not being able to figure out the problem

```
  public void getPic() {


         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setType("image/*");
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
         startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                 "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                Log.v("IMAGE PATH====>>>> ",selectedImagePath);
            }
        }
    }
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: Could you pls post the code you are using now to get the file name from the activity list

Answer (score 0):

make the change in your getPath() function as follows

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {

        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Hope this will help you.. :)

Comment: what i need to import for getContentResolver().query() ?

Comment: i tired it but its not recognizing  getContentResolver()

Comment: no need to import anything, just replace 'this' with the correct context

Comment: try with yourActivityName.this